# How to show page footer on first page?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

After adding some data in the report header, the page footer for the first page got lost. The data in the report header is a page long and on the second page starts the details. For the second page and for the rest of the pages I get the page footer.

Is there a way to show the page footer on the first page?

Answer (score 0):

you could try removing the header section's "keep together" property.

Comment: No, it seems it didn't worked. In my detail section I have a section that has new page before.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a "dummy" footer by:

1. Create an additional header section
2. Duplicate your footer in your new header section
3. In Section Expert for your new header section, check "New Page After"
4. In Section Expert for your old header section, uncheck "New Page After"

Fixed!